# comment-only(?) mode in Visual Studio or any IDEs

Tags: visual-studio, comments

I'm fairly new to programming and I often write comments all together after coding is done.

The problem is I sometimes find myself modifying the code by accident, so I was wondering if there's any way to protect the code while I'm on writing comments exclusively.

I would like to know if such mode exists in Visual Studio or any IDEs out there.

Comment: Waiting until after to add the comments is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VS code editor you can collapse some code constructs such as namespaces, methods, conditionally compiled areas, or classes, but that's probably where you want to put your comments.